# Control-m scheduling job for 2 options

Tags: control-m

A job has a predecessor. So as aoon as the predecessor is finished the job starts running.  But is it possible to schedule the job as follows:
1)when the predecessor fonishes before say 5 o clock the job should wait until 5 to start.
2) When the predecessor finished after 5 oclock then the job should wait for it to finish

Answer (score 0):

Edit the second job to have a "From Time" of 17:00. If you have a condition between the 2 jobs then they will run as you describe.